Understanding proof of the error bound for Simpson's quadrature rule
I have found the following proof of the error bound for Simpson's quadrature rule:
Using Newton's interpolation method, we derive a cubic polynomial $p_3(x)$ that interpolates $f(x)$ at the points $a, b$, and $(a + b)/2$ and additionally interpolating $f'(x)$ at $(a + b)/2$. Therefore, $p_3(x)$ is given by
$$p_3(x) = p_2(x) + c_2 (x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right).$$
Integrating both sides, we obtain
\begin{align*}
        \int_a^b p_3(x) \ dx = \int_a^b p_2(x) \ dx + c_2 \int_a^b (x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
Noting that the cubic function $(x - a)(x - b)(x - (a + b)/2))$ is an odd function with a root at $(a + b)/2$, we have that its integral on the interval $[a, b]$ evaluates to 0. Hence, we have
\begin{align*}
        \int_a^b p_3(x) \ dx &= \int_a^b p_2(x) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
Now, we have that the error may be represented as
\begin{align*}
        E_S &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_2(x) \ dx \\
        &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_3(x) \ dx.
    \end{align*}
From the study of polynomial interpolation, we know the expression of the error of $f(x) - p_3(x)$, and thus we have
\begin{align*}
        E_s &= \int_a^b f(x) - p_3(x) \ dx \\
        &= \int_a^b \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!}(x - a)(x - b)\left(x - \frac{a + b}{2}\right)^2 \ dx \\
        &= \frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)}{4!} \cdot -\frac{(b - a)^5}{120} \\
        &= -\frac{f^{(4)}(\xi)(b - a)^5}{2880}.
    \end{align*}
Some questions:
Why exactly is it important that we derive $\int_a^b p_3(x) = \int_a^b p_2(x)$? We know equally as much about the error of $f(x) - p_2(x)$, so why must we express it in terms of $p_3(x)$? Furthermore, why is the $(x - (a + b)/2))$ term in the expansion of $f(x) - p_2(x)$ squared? This seems like a clever approach compared with some more common approaches to the proof, I am just having a hard time understanding some of the nuances.

Crossposted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4907457/307944
